#  Search by substring on strings which map to id

Tags: java

What would be the best way to implement search by substring on Strings(around 5000 entity names in application) which map to entityId.

I want to implement it so that I could put searched suggestions to the user as he types in one or more characters.For e.g I would want to be able to suggest all entities starting with his queried substring as he does the search.

Looking forward to store them in the application scope itself to avoid frequent retrievals from DB.

Comment: Needs more context information. To put it a different way: what in the heck are you talking about?

Comment: Can the entity be anywhere in the string? How long can the strings be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need some sort of [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure.  As the user types characters, you could return a subset of leaf-nodes under the node mapped by what they've already typed.

Google has a [trie implementation](http://code.google.com/p/trie/) you could possibly adapt.

Comment: I was exactly thinking something like this.. but this is not fortunately a production quality code that could be used directly...

Comment: Granted.  There's another implementation here http://stevedaskam.wordpress.com/2009/05/28/trie-structures/ - I haven't done an exhaustive search for implementations; perhaps there's one in the Apache Commons library?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if understand exactly what you need (sorry), but I had success by searching/indexing/caching Strings and decreasing database access, by using Apache Lucene.

You might want to take a look at [Apache Lucene's Site](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

Hope it helps.